# how to get the maximally independent vectors given a set of vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

If I am given a set of vectors (they can be provided as the column vectors of a matrix), and I want to get the maximally independent vectors, what is the best way to go about it?

I could add one vector to the result set at a time to see if the rank of the newly formed matrix is increased or not. But I feel it is not very efficient. Of course, I could go back to do Gauss elimination to work this out. But I am just wondering if there is a better (efficient and numerically stable and robut) approach to this problem.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Feel the addition by watching the rank increasing is probably not valid. We can do deletion by watching if the rank is decreasing though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *maximally independent*?

Comment: @Phonon: I meant any set of independent vectors, adding one more of the rest would produce a dependent set.

Answer (score 3):

This code will do the trick.  It's a little bit dirty because it grows `rInd` on the fly, which isn't the most efficient, but the idea is more important.  It uses the QR decomposition, which is basically Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.  From this, it goes through the rows of r until it finds the next vector in `A` that adds something linearly independent to the currently known basis.

```
iUnderConsideration = 1;

[q,r] = qr(A);
rInd = [];
for j = 1:size(r,2),
    if(r(iUnderConsideration,j) ~= 0)
        rInd = [rInd r(:,j)];
        iUnderConsideration = iUnderConsideration + 1;
    end
    if(iUnderConsideration > size(r,1))
        break;
    end
end

q*rInd  %here's your answer
```

As a side note, this code will chose the vectors of your matrix `A` without changing them.  `svd` wouldn't give you these directly.

Comment: Note that this assumes that your vectors are the column vectors of A.

Comment: @Ben-Uri This was part of the assumptions by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
[U,S,V]=svd(vectors);
U(1:size(vectors,1),1:size(vectors,2))=vectors;
```

U now contains the original vectors plus an optimally orthogonal set.

Answer (score 1):

Doing RREF and looking for columns with the leading zeros is your best bet:

```
matr(:,logical(sum(rref(matr)==1)))
```

This will give you the basis for the column space of the matrix.

Comment: this is using Gauss-Jordan with partial pivoting. This is one of the methods I mentioned above. Would this be not that stable numerically?

Comment: I was not aware that it is not numerically stable. Will remove my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

[SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) is your answer.

The [MATLAB reference for SVD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/svd.html).