# Find largest subset of linearly independent vectors with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to create a matlab function that finds the largest subset of linearly independent vectors in a matrix A.

Initialize the output of the program to be 0, which corresponds to the empty set (containing no column vectors). Scanning the columns of A from left to right one by one; if adding the current column vector to the set of linearly independent vectors found so far makes the new set of vectors linearly DEPENDENT, then skip this vector, otherwise add this vector to the solution set; and move to the next column.

```
function [ out ] = maxindependent(A) 
%MAXINDEPENDENT takes a matrix A and produces an array in which the columns 
%are a subset of independent vectors with maximum size. 
[r c]= size(A); 
out=0; 
A=A(:,rank(A)) 
for jj=1:c 
  M=[A A(:,jj)] 
  if rank(M)~=size(M,2) 
    A=A 
  elseif rank(M)==size(M,2) 
    A=M 
  end 
end 
out=A 

if max(out)==0 
 0; 
end 

end
```

Comment: So, ***what have you tried***?

Answer (score 0):

The number of linearly independent vectors in a matrix is equal to the [rank of the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_rank), and a particular subset of linearly independent vectors is not unique. Any 'largest subset' of linearly independent vectors will have size equal to the rank.

There is a function for this in MATLAB:

```
n = rank(A);
```

The algorithm you described is not necessary; you should just use the SVD. There is a concise way to do it here: [how to get the maximally independent vectors given a set of vectors in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721523/how-to-get-the-maximally-independent-vectors-given-a-set-of-vectors-in-matlab)

Comment: I need to write a script that does this manually by going through the columns of A and adding that column vector to the vectors in A that are linearly independent.
Here is what I have so far...


function [ out ] = maxindependent(A)

%MAXINDEPENDENT takes a matrix A and produces an array in which the columns
%are a subset of independent vectors with maximum size. 
[r c]= size(A);
out=0;
A=A(:,rank(A))
for jj=1:c
    M=[A A(:,jj)]
    if rank(M)~=size(M,2)
        A=A
    elseif rank(M)==size(M,2)
            A=M
    end
end
out=A
if max(out)==0
    0;
end
end

Comment: Sigh...I copied that code into your original post, which is what you should have done in the first place.